# How to access index of an array from path clue string

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I want to access element of an index of an array but that path or index  i have in string i have no idea what to do for example

**This is Array**

```
$array = [
    "level1" [
        [
            "level2" => [
                "level3" => [["test1"],["test2"],["test3"],["test4"],["test5"]]
                "lavel3_1 => ...
            ], 
        ],
    ]
    ...
];
```

**This is the index or a path clue**

```
$path = "level1->0->level2->level3->5";
```

So According to path i have to access like 
this

```
print_r($array["level1"][0]["level2"]["level3"][5]);
```

how to do that because path in a string and its dynamic,
do i need to use `eval()` function

Comment: @u_mulder it will help me, Thanks!